# Dependency issues while installing curl-devel

Tags: centos, centos5, curl, redmine, rubygems

I'm trying to run the `passenger-install-apache2-module` so I can install Redmine on CentOS 5.8, but `passenger-install-apache2-module` tells me I need `Curl development headers with SSL support`, which it tells me I can install using `yum install curl-devel`, however, when I run that I get the following results:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, protectbase
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.pbone.net
 * extras: ftp.pbone.net
 * remi: remi-mirror.dedipower.com
 * updates: ftp.pbone.net
120 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
0 packages excluded due to repository protections
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package curl-devel.i386 0:7.15.5-15.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: curl = 7.15.5-15.el5 for package: curl-devel
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
curl-devel-7.15.5-15.el5.i386 from base has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: curl = 7.15.5-15.el5 is needed by package curl-devel-7.15.5-15.el5.i386 (base)
Error: Missing Dependency: curl = 7.15.5-15.el5 is needed by package curl-devel-7.15.5-15.el5.i386 (base)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Now I'm not amazing with linux stuff, however, I think this tells me that I need version curl if I want to install curl-devel (makes sense). But I know I have curl install, and I do `curl -V` to test if it is actually install, and this gives me:

```
curl 7.21.7 (i686-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5 libssh2/1.2.7
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
```

So I think the problem is the difference in versions, however, I have no idea where to go from here.

So my question is, how do I install curl-devel properly?

BTW: I did try what yum told me to try at the end:

```
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the same version of curl-devel and curl.
The package passenger-install-apache2-module require the version 7.15.5-15.el5 of curl-devel so you need to update curl to version 7.15.5-15.el5.
You have installed a greater version of curl package, the version is 7.21.7.

Your server use as repository rpmbone, this repository contains curl version 7.15.5-15.el5.
These are the packages url:
ftp.centos.org/5.8/os/x86_64/CentOS/curl-7.15.5-15.el5.x86_64.rpm 
ftp.centos.org/5.8/os/i386/CentOS/curl-7.15.5-15.el5.i386.rpm

You can try to remove curl.7.21.7 if it isn't a dependency of other package and install curl and curl-devel 7.15.5-15 using the command "yum install curl-7.15.5-15 curl-devel--7.15.5-15"

Comment: Removed curl, but it can't find those packages, also I tried `yum install curl curl-devel`, but giving me the following error: `Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/lib/libcurl.so.3.0.0 from install of curl-7.15.5-15.el5.i386 conflicts with file from package compat-libcurl3-7.15.5-1.el5.remi.i386`

Comment: Thanks I can now install Git because I made sure curl and curl-devel were the same version 1. yum remove curl
2. yum remove curl-devel
3. yum install curl-7.12.1 curl-7.12.1
4. yum install git